# Why am I not able to set rounded corners for ImageView?

Tags: java, android, gaussian, rounded-corners

I am making a launcher in which, I want the dock to look something like this:

[image]

As you can see, there are two main features of the dock.

1)Gaussian Blur

2)Rounded Corners

For rounded corners, I used this code:

```
RoundedBitmapDrawable RBD = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(getResources(), bmp);

RBD.setCornerRadius(40.0f);

RBD.setAntiAlias(true);
```

Where bmp is the bottom part of the Image (which I cropped programmatically)

For Gaussian blur, I used an API

```
GaussianBlur.with(this).size(80).radius(25).put(croppedDrawable, dock);
```

Where, croppedDrawable is drawable of the cropped Bitmap of the bottom part of the image.

Here is the full code:

```
//Cropping image to fit the dimensions of the dock
            bmp.setDensity(Bitmap.DENSITY_NONE);
            bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, (int) dock.getY(), Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels, dock.getHeight());
        //Rounded Corners
        RoundedBitmapDrawable RBD = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(getResources(), bmp);

        //The radius of corners
        RBD.setCornerRadius(40.0f);

        //I have no idea why this is used
        RBD.setAntiAlias(true);

        //Now that the image has roundedCorners, Gaussian blur can be applied
        //For this, I have to convert RBD to a drawable. It cannot be cast 
        //directly, hence, I am first converting it to a bitmap and then to
        //a drawable

        Bitmap bmp2 = RBD.getBitmap();
        Drawable croppedGaussianDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bmp2);
        GaussianBlur.with(this).size(80).radius(25).put(croppedGaussianDrawable, dock);
```

Something's wrong because the output I am getting is:

[image]

Only Gaussian Blur has been applied to the dock. 
I have no idea what the error is. I have tried using other methods, but they were of no use.

Can someone please tell me what is the problem with the code? Where am I going wrong? Why aren't the corners of the dock image rounded?

Comment: `RoundedBitmapDrawable#getBitmap()` is not going to return a `Bitmap` with rounded corners. It just returns the backing `Bitmap`. Internally, a shader is created with that `Bitmap` to do the rounded corner draw. You'll need to blur the `Bitmap` before you pass it `RoundedBitmapDrawable`.